# Need an Image map area clicked to select corresponding radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm struggling with some javascript, or jquery here. Basically we've taken a simple image of a pc, and created three image mapped areas upon it. Area 1 is the monitors screen, area 2 is the front of the tower, and area 3 is the keyboard.

Below that I've set up three rows of radio buttons, with three buttons in each row, with the idea of capturing the order they select from the image map. What I'm trying to make happen is when the image map 1 is clicked to have the first radio button on the fist row clicked, and then record the order of the selection from there, so that when the next area of the image map is clicked, say area 2, the second button on the second row is clicked. I also need them to be un-selectable if clicked upon twice. I will add hover effects at a latter time to make this intuitive.

So far I've got it where the image map area clicked will select the radio button from the first row that corresponds to the image map selected, say they click area 3, then the third radio button on the fist row is selected. However if they then click area 2 from the image map, then the second button on the first row is selected, and what I need it to do is select the second button on the second row for that. I hope this makes sense. Basically we're trying to record the order of their selection with radio buttons. 3 image map areas, three buttons per row, with three rows.

This is what I have so far.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var order = 0;
    function retainOrder(stuff) {
        var findMe = "CUST_" + stuff;
        var orgLoc = document.getElementById(findMe);
        if (orgLoc.checked)
        {
            order=order + 1;
            var newString = "RADIO" + radio + "_" + stuff;
            document.getElementById(newString).checked = true;  
        }
        else {
            var anotherString = "RADIO" + radio + "_" + stuff;
            document.getElementById(anotherString).checked = false; 
            order=order-1;
        }

    }
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="imagemap"><img src="http://img716.imageshack.us/img716/8287/3ylp.jpg" width="275" height="207" usemap="#Map" border="0" onclick="document.getElementById('radio0').checked = true">
  <map name="Map">

    <area shape="poly" coords="105,26,107,126,257,140,256,27" href="#" id="CUST_1 "name="CUST:1" value="1" %CUST:1% onclick="document.getElementById('radio0').checked = true"/>

    <area shape="poly" coords="10,21,14,178,71,184,69,19" href="#" name="CUST:2" %CUST:2% onclick="document.getElementById('radio1').checked = true"/>

    <area shape="poly" coords="113,145,94,172,241,192,251,164,250,164" href="#" %CUST:3% name="CUST:3" onclick="document.getElementById('radio2').checked = true"/>

  </map>

<p>

<div>
<input type="radio" name="radios" id="radio0" value="0" />
<input type="radio" name="radios" id="radio1" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="radios" id="radio2" value="2" />
</div>
<div>
<input type="radio" name="radios" id="radio3" value="0" />
<input type="radio" name="radios" id="radio4" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="radios" id="radio5" value="2" />
</div>
<div>
<input type="radio" name="radios" id="radio6" value="0" />
<input type="radio" name="radios" id="radio7" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="radios" id="radio8" value="2" />
</div>
```

If anyone can help me out here I would be truly grateful. Thank you.

Comment: See my example below. There are several ways to select the radio buttons, I used the `ID` attribute for each radio button. Unsure what you wanted to do when all 3 are selected, so I reset the counter to start over. Optionally, you can put at top of click event: `if (click_order >= 6) return false;`  If any answer is helpful to you, please upvote. Remember to choose a correct answer when satisfied, in order to close the question.

Comment: Thank you very much, that helps a lot. There is one thing I may have neglected to mention however, I also need it to be un-selectable as well, so that it removes their pick from the radio buttons if it's clicked on twice. I'm going to add hover effects to the image map so this becomes intuitive later.

Comment: That's really a different question. I suggest that you close this question (upvote all helpful answers and select the answer you like best) and formulate a different question. You already have two jsFiddles on which to build your new question (hint: press `Fork` button). *It will also place your new question at the top of the list.*

Answer (score 2):

Here's an edited Vanilla JS solution.

```
window.onload = function () {
    var order = 0, checkedAreas = [],
        mapClick = function (e) {
            var m, n, start,
                buttonNumber = e.target.id.split('_').pop(),
                buttonName = 'radios' + buttonNumber,
                buttons = document.getElementsByName(buttonName);
            if (!checkedAreas[buttonNumber]) {
                buttons[order].checked = true;
                order += 1;
                checkedAreas[buttonNumber] = order;
            } else {
                start = checkedAreas[buttonNumber];
                checkedAreas[buttonNumber] = 0;
                buttons[start - 1].checked = false;
                for (m = 0; m < 3; m++) {
                    buttons = document.getElementsByName('radios' + m);
                    for (n = start; n < 3; n++) {
                        if (buttons[n].checked) {
                            checkedAreas[m] = checkedAreas[m] - 1;
                            buttons[n].checked = false;
                            buttons[n - 1].checked = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                order -= 1;
            }
        };
    document.getElementById('Map').addEventListener('click', mapClick);
};
```

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zQJ4m/5/).

I've edited the code after your comment. Now it toggles the corresponding radio button when clicking an area, and moves other checkings using clicking order.

I've added named groups to your HTML, like below. You can change the order of the devices ("columns") by changing the order in input groups.

```
<input type="radio" name="radios1" id="radio0" value="0" />
<input type="radio" name="radios0" id="radio1" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="radios2" id="radio2" value="2" />

<input type="radio" name="radios1" id="radio3" value="0" />
<input type="radio" name="radios0" id="radio4" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="radios2" id="radio5" value="2" />

<input type="radio" name="radios1" id="radio6" value="0" />
<input type="radio" name="radios0" id="radio7" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="radios2" id="radio8" value="2" />
```

Also I've changed numbers in `id`s of `areas` to zero-based.

Comment: Ah thank you, I should have been more specific I believe on the un-selection part, as I do need them to be 'un-selectable'

Comment: @William Hmm... that causes a lot of looping, when rearranging the remained selections. I've to think about this for a moment : ).

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'm also trying to get it to work, so if I find a solution I'll post it here. Thanks again!

Comment: ugh this one really has me banging my head against the wall, I'm used to using javascript for nav bars, and forms, this is a tough one! Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: I could kiss ya!!!! j/k anyway that's very close to what I need, however instead of assigning the radio buttons unique id's, is there a way to make it so that say the screen is always row 1, pc is always row 2, and keyboard is always row 3? that way our programing can just run down the list seeing in what order they where selected? For example starting off when I click the keyboard, that populates radio button 3 in row 1, then when I click the screen that populates radio button 1 in row 2? Next the PC populating radio button 2 in row 3? You've been a big help and thank you very much!!!

Comment: What I mean by that is say I click the keyboard first, I then need that to punch radio button 3 in row 1. Currently that punches radio button three in row three. I hope that clears up my meaning. Thanks!!!

Comment: Okay I understand that, but I need the keyboard to check the 3rd button in the first row, so that the radio buttons are checking the order of selection, sequentially. Then if I click say the screen next, it checks the 1st radio button on the 2nd row. In the end we're going to have over 90 of these, and having it scan all 90 each time is going to slow the program down we're afraid. I really appreciate all your help, thanks a bunch!

Comment: @William Hmm... I think I've finally understood what you mean, like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zQJ4m/4/)? The JS is the same as in previous snippet, only the order of the radio buttons is changed.

Comment: Getting closer, only the screen is 1, desktop is 2, keyboard is 3, I think it has desktop at 1 currently. You're a wiz buddy thanks so much!!!!

Comment: I got into it, and edited my post: Getting closer, only the screen is 1, desktop is 2, keyboard is 3, I think it has desktop at 1 currently. You're a wiz buddy thanks so much!!!!

Comment: @William There is something going on, jsFiddle is not working well. I think we should remove some comments here, the thread is far too long... [Just swap the `radios0` and `radios1`](http://jsfiddle.net/zQJ4m/5/) in the `div`s...

Answer (score 1):

This should give you an idea of what to do:

[working jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/JbWEt/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    click_order = 0;

    $('map area').click(function() {
        var areaID = $(this).attr('id');
        var areaNum = areaID.split('_')[1];
        areaNum = areaNum - 1 + click_order; //-1 b/c radio btns are zero-based
        $('#radio' +areaNum).prop('checked',true);
        (click_order >= 6) ? click_order = 0 : click_order += 3 ;
    });
});
```